# Error in ggplot In R

Tags: r, error-handling, ggplot2

I wanted to plot time series data in R by using ggplot but I have faced with this error:

```
Error in continuous_scale(aesthetics, "date", identity, breaks = breaks,  : 
unused argument(s) (format = "%b-%Y")
```

Syntax:

```
ggplot(p29, aes(dt, ambtemp)) + geom_line() +
    scale_x_date(format = "%b-%Y") + xlab("") + ylab("Tempreture")
```

File Name: `p29`

```
  ambtemp                  dt surtemp
1   -1.14 2007-09-29 00:01:57  -2.712
2   -1.12 2007-09-29 00:03:57  -2.775
3   -1.33 2007-09-29 00:05:57  -2.712
4   -1.44 2007-09-29 00:07:57  -2.837
5   -1.54 2007-09-29 00:09:57  -2.775
6   -1.29 2007-09-29 00:11:57  -2.900
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In function `scale_x_date()` you should write `labels=date_format("%b-%Y")`. Also column `dt` should be formatted as `Date`.

```
library(scales)
p29$dt=as.Date(p29$dt, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")    
ggplot(p29, aes(dt, ambtemp)) + geom_line() +
scale_x_date(labels=date_format ("%b-%Y")) + xlab("") + ylab("Tempreture")
```

To show hours and minutes, instead of function `scale_x_date()` you should use `scale_x_datetime()` and write `labels=date_format("%H:%M")`. To control breaks argument `breaks=date_breaks()` is used. Also column `dt` should be formatted as `POSIXt`.

```
library(scales)
p29$dt=strptime(p29$dt, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
ggplot(p29, aes(dt, ambtemp)) + geom_line() +
scale_x_datetime(breaks = date_breaks("5 min"),labels=date_format("%H:%M")) + xlab("") + ylab("Tempreture")
```

Comment: It presents almost a straight and with no fluctuation. How Can i modify it to present fluctuation, sensitively?

Comment: Could you say what exactly you want to see on x axis - month, day or hours and does your data contains only one date (2007-09-29) or several?

Comment: My data only include 2007/09/29 and I wanted to see just the hours in x axis

Comment: @user1885733 updated my solution to work with minutes and hours